# How to saving the input form to localStorage but there are 2 bugs i have

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have 2 errors, the first is

```
index.html:91 Uncaught ReferenceError: handleUserLogin is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:91:70)
onclick @ index.html:91
```

the second is when the user typing their name after hitting the login button, the localStorage should be saving but there is no key and the value saved but when i check at the console, the value is shown up.

My script and HTML

```js
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function() {
  async function handleUserLogin() {

    let formInput = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    let userInput = formInput;

    if (userInput !== "") {
      alert(`Welcome ${userInput}`);
    } else if (typeof(userInput) === "number") {
      alert(`Must be a sentences not a number`);
    } else {
      alert("Please fill this form before antoher actions")
    }

    return console.log(userInput);
  }
  loginButton.addEventListener("click", handleUserLogin);
});

async function createLocalDataStorage() {
  "use strict";

  try {
    localStorage.setItem("userInput", await userInput);
    console.log("User Input has been saved!", {}, userInput);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error at the : " + err);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-login-with-form-dbLocalStorage">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="nama" placeholder="fill this blank forms" />
  </form>
  <button onclick="handleUserLogin()" type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</div>

<script src="script.js" text="javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="handleUserLogin()"` can't access the function inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {` - but since you do `loginButton.addEventListener("click", handleUserLogin);` there's no need to ALSO have `<button onclick="handleUserLogin()"`

Comment: Also, I have never seen returning `console.log`. What's the point of it?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic  just a logging statement when the user filled the form. if succeded console.log ()will throwing an argument "success to login" within the username. if not, console.log()  will throwing the false.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

1. Use the handleSubmit on the form submit event instead of the button click event which should not be inline
2. use event.preventDefault() in the first line of the event handler if you do not want to submit at all
3. Absolutely no need for async anywhere in your script
4. Your scopes are wrong. If you want to use DOMContentLoaded, then all the variables used in that event has to be defined in that event.
5. console.log returns undefined so don't use return on that

Here is an updated script - note the catch will be called due to localStorage not being allowed in stacksnippets

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  const msg = document.getElementById("message");
  const handleUserLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    let userInput = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    if (userInput === "") {
      msg.textContent = "Please fill this form before another action";
      return;
    }
    if (!/[a-zA-Z ]+/.test(userInput)) {
      msg.textContent = "Please use only alphabetic characters and space";
      return;
    }
    msg.textContent = `Welcome ${userInput}`;
    try {
      localStorage.setItem("userInput", userInput);
      console.log("User Input has been saved!", {}, userInput);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error at the : " + err);
    }
  };
  form.addEventListener("submit", handleUserLogin);
});
```

```html
<div class="simple-login-with-form-dbLocalStorage">
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="nama" placeholder="fill this blank form" />
    <button id="login">Login</button>
  </form>

  <span id="message"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me sir with pleasure, why are you giving  return nothing in those 2 if statements? also what is this "!/[a-zA-Z ]+/"?

Comment: The `/ ... /` is called a regular expression. The `!` is NOT, [az-A-Z ] is all letters from a-z in lower and upper case plus a space and the + means 1 or more of them. So were are testing that the if value is NOT one or more a-Z or space, give an error

Comment: The two returns just mean do nothing in those two cases